# Draw jfreechart in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to read a CSV file and have projected the results from a servlet. How can I generate a jfreechart(multi-series bar chart) for the results since the result comes from a 2d array.

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MCA_summary</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet MCA_summary at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            String fName = "D:/MCA_data/mca_test.csv";
            String thisLine;
            String date,status;
            String tempDate[];
            String[][] dateStatus=new String[3][];
            String[][] tempDateStatus;
            //String[][] dateStatus=new String[3][];
            int count=0,dateCount=0; 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fName);
            DataInputStream myInput=new DataInputStream(fis);
            int i=0,k=0,l=0,j=0,a,b; 

           while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String strar[] = thisLine.split(",");

                for(j=1;j<3;j++)
                 {
                    if(i!=0) 
                    {
                       //System.out.print(" " +strar[j]+ " ");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //System.out.print("" +strar[j]+ " ");
                    }
                    i++;
                    System.out.println();
                 }
                if(l != 0)
                {
                    date=strar[1];
                    status = strar[2];
                    i=0;
                    for(k=0;k<dateCount;k++)
                    {
                        if(dateStatus[0][k].equals(date))
                        {
                            i=k;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(k == dateCount)
                    {
                        tempDateStatus=new String[3][dateCount+1];
                        for(a=0;a<dateCount;a++)
                        {
                            for(b=0;b<3;b++)
                            {
                            tempDateStatus[b][a]=dateStatus[b][a];  
                            }
                        }
                        //dateStatus[0][k] = new String[3];
                        dateStatus = new String[3][dateCount+1];
                        for(a=0;a<dateCount;a++)
                        {
                            for(b=0;b<3;b++)
                            {
                            dateStatus[b][a]=tempDateStatus[b][a];  
                            }
                        }
                        dateStatus[0][k]=date;
                        dateCount++;
                        dateStatus[1][k]="0";
                        dateStatus[2][k]="0";
                        i=k;
                    }  
                    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("succesfull"))
                    {
                        dateStatus[1][i] =Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(dateStatus[1][i])+1));
                    }
                    else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
                    {
                        dateStatus[2][i] = Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(dateStatus[2][i])+1));
                    }

                }
                l++;

                 //tempDate = strar[1].split(" ");
                 //date = tempDate[0];
            }  
           out.println("<table border=2>");
           out.println("<tr><td> Date</td><td>Successful</td><td>Error</td></tr>");
            for(i=0;i<dateCount;i++)
                {
                    out.println("<tr>");
                    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
                    {
                       out.println("<td>");
                       out.print(dateStatus[k][i]);
                       out.println("</td>");
                    }
                    out.println("</tr>");
                    //System.out.println();
                }

           out.println("</table>");


        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
```

The CSV is in the form of:

```
Object Name,Ongoing Time Stamp,Error/Successfull,End Time Stamp,Difference
MCA000002917 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 11:39,4:16:25
MCA000004503 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 8:56,1:30:23
MCA000004508 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 9:08,0:03:00
MCA000004509 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 10:31,1:15:48
MCA000004445 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 11:09,0:34:07
MCA000003833 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 12:00,0:17:31
MCA000004507 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 11:47,0:02:24
MCA000002107 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 14:07,2:11:20
MCA000004487 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 12:05,0:02:30
MCA000004513 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:01,1:08:17
MCA000003862 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:09,0:06:08
MCA000004478 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:18,0:13:13
MCA000004519 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:35,0:22:15
MCA000004414 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:37,0:11:54
MCA000004380 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:00,0:17:12
MCA000004520 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 15:53,0:07:41
MCA000004525 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:08,0:12:52
MCA000004524 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:05,0:02:50
MCA000004527 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:15,0:02:49
MCA000004529 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:17,0:01:59
MCA000004442 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:29,0:06:13
MCA000003580 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:30,0:05:27
MCA000000983 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:08,0:35:04
MCA000003614 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:39,0:03:55
MCA000004532 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:47,0:01:42
MCA000003726 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 16:59,0:04:01
MCA000004526 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:15,0:09:28
MCA000004537 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:28,0:03:08
MCA000004536 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:48,0:15:19
MCA000003372 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:43,0:07:50
MCA000003863 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:57,0:04:07
MCA000004531 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 17:57,0:01:57
MCA000000985 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 18:18,0:15:32
MCA000004541 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 18:06,0:01:10
MCA000002042 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 20:29,2:13:46
MCA000004518 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 20:45,0:12:36
MCA000004555 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 20:37,0:01:50
MCA000004556 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/7/2016 20:46,0:01:19
MCA000004557 A.1,11/7/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 0:02,3:09:33
MCA000004538 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 9:32,1:49:43
MCA000004559 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 8:00,0:04:50
MCA000004560 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 8:19,0:03:32
MCA000004157 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 8:33,0:07:34
MCA000004540 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 11:09,2:34:10
ECA000000141 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 9:43,0:00:21
MCA000004545 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 11:38,1:45:11
MCA000004372 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 12:04,0:21:34
MCA000004563 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 11:48,0:02:34
MCA000004565 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 11:57,0:01:51
MCA000004567 A.1,11/8/2016,Error,11/8/2016 16:05,3:32:04
MCA000004572 A.1,11/8/2016,Succesfull,11/8/2016 16:38,4:02:55
```

The code counts the number of success/ error for a particluar date from column 2 and 3.

Comment: What is your question? Here is text-only algorithm, can't see jfreechar preparation. Main html usually have <img> tag, body of produced image is taken from other request.